# Running a Distinct on a record

Tags: c#, linq

In `LINQ` if the result that I have is the a list of whole records from the database and I want to do a `Distinct` on one column of this record, How do I do that?

Comment: you should make an effort first

Answer (score 0):

You could try something as simple as:

```
var distincts = records.Select(x=>x.ColumnName).Distinct();
```

Comment: I still want the whole record after selecting distinct ones based on that column, does it return the whole records ?

Comment: The above query initially projects each record to the value of the `ColumnName` and then returns the distinct values. So, no it doesn;t return the whole records. Furthermore, that you are looking for without making any other assumptions is impossible. For instance, let that we have two records with the same value for `ColumnName`, which one of the two we should pick? One option it would be to group them bu the `ColumnName` and take the first record of each group but honestly I don't if that's you are looking for.